# Show that for the subsets A and B that A=B

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ and $B$ be the following subsets of $\mathbb R^2$

$$
A=\{(x,x+y^2)\,|\,x,y\in \mathbb R\}\\
B=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2\,|\,b\geq a\}
$$

Show that $A=B$

I’ve reasoned it out that If $A=B$ then it must be the case that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$. If $A\neq B$, then there exists $x\in A \setminus B$ (or $x\in B\setminus A$), however $A\subseteq B$, clearly $x\in B$. This is a contradiction.
So $A=B$.
However I haven’t the slightest idea how to incorporating the sets themselves into the proof, please help.

Comment: Don't ask the same question again... (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4079239/showing-that-two-subsets-in-mathbb-r2-are-the-same)

Answer (score 4):

$A$ consists of all points that can be written on the form $(x, x+y^2)$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. $B$ consists of all points where the right coordinate is greater than or equal to the left coordinate. Here is what we need to prove:

If a point is of the form $(x, x+y^2)$ for some real numbers $x, y$, is the right coordinate greater than or equal to the left coordinate? In other words, do we have $A\subseteq B$?

If a point $(a, b)$ has $a\leq b$, can we find real numbers $x, y$ such that $(a, b) = (x, x + y^2)$? In other words, do we have $B\subseteq A$?